# Can <cfdirectory> location work with site-relative locations?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I've noticed that when using the  tag to create a directory and then subsequently upload/delete files using , it wants a full-path from the root of the drive that website is hosted on. I would rather use site-relative locations if possible.

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
<cfdirectory action="create" directory="users/files/myfiles">
```

But this ends up creating a new folder structure of `C:\users\files\myfiles` in the hard drive. In order to get it to make the directory within my site itself I have to write this:

```
<cfdirectory action="create" directory="/inetpub/wwwroot/mysite/users/files/myfiles">
```

I don't like the idea of having to put the fully qualified path. Its not very flexible for my needs.

Its the same issue with deleting a file. I have to put in the file path starting from its location on the hard drive, rather than relative within the website's folder. Is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use expandpath(); this will lookup the site root for you. That way you don't need to hard code it.

i.e,

`<cfset rootdir=expandPath('/users/files/myfiles')>

<cfdirectory action="create" directory="#rootdir#">`

Comment: Seems to work, thank you. Is this the way it is meant to be done? That is, <cfdirectory> and <cffile> need full paths to work not just site-relative ones?

Comment: correct: cffile and cfdirectory are physical file manipulation tags, so they're expecting the full path of the physical file (which may be different from the URL etc, or you may need to manipulate files outside the webroot).